# Registration form - Notice: Undefined index

Tags: html, forms, registration, php

Here is my register form:

```
<p>Please fill out all fields</p><br>

<form method="POST" action="login/login.php">   
<!-- name is the VARIABLE -->
Username: <input type="text" name="username"></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"></br>    
</form> 
    
</br>
</br>
<form method="POST" action="login/process.php" "> </br>
<input type='submit' value='submit registration'/>
</form>
```

here is my process.php file:

```
<?php 
print "<center>";
$Username = $_POST["username"]; 
$Password = $_POST["password"];
$Email  = $_POST["email"];
?>

<?php
include "../shopdb/connection.php";

$query="INSERT INTO USERS (ID, Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('','$Username','$Password','$Email')";

mysql_query($query,$connect);

?>
```

I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\IIS\login\process.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\IIS\login\process.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\IIS\login\process.php on line 5
>
> You are successfully connected to the database.

(the bottom message is a part of the connection script I added to show I'm connected to the DB)..

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is your question? Is the error message a bit unclear to you?

Comment: Or is that merely a question how forms in HTML work?

Comment: Or do you want to know how both forms can have the same fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your submit button in a form that is separate from the form that your text fields are in. This should work:

```
<form method="POST" action="login/process.php">
    <!-- name is the VARIABLE -->
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"></br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"></br>
    <input type='submit' value='submit registration'/>
</form>
```

By the way, you should be checking to see if variables exist **before** you use them:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    echo 'Variable is set and I can use it!';
}
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you very much. I've learned quite alot from that. I'll vote as top answer asap (says I cannot do so for 5 mins)

Answer (score 0):

Your `submit` input needs to be in the same `<form>` as the other inputs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @chris explain to me how it does not answer the question